# Phoenix/Elixir - protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for #PID<0.890.0>

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

In my Phoenix app I am using a Genserver (Paginator) to maintain state for pagination purposes.

I have this in my PageController:

```
def index(conn, params) do
  {page_entries, current_page} = case Map.get(params, "page_entries") do
                                  nil ->
                                    {:ok, page_entries} = Paginator.start_link()
                                    {page_entries, 1}
                                  page_entries ->
                                    {page_entries, Map.get(params, "current_page")}
                                 end
  # do some stuff
  render conn, "index.html", page_entries: page_entries, current_page: current_page
end
```

In my template index.html.eex I have this link:

```
link "Next→", to: page_path(@conn, :index, page_entries: @page_entries, current_page: @current_page+1)
```

But I get this error:

```
protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for #PID<0.890.0>
```

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html):

> By default, Phoenix implements this protocol for integers, binaries, atoms, maps and structs.

How do I send the process id across pages through links? Is there any way to do it without the process data appearing in the query string?

Comment: I would say that this sounds generally like a bad idea. What if the process goes down? Or in case you need to have multiple machines, what if the nest request goes to another one?

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass `PID` across. `PID` is not a long-lived entity, it changes when the process crashes and is restarted by the supervisor, it differs amongst different nodes. Pass either `name` or an `id` instead.

[`GenServer.start_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3) has an optional `opts` parameter, where one might pass a name:

```
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
```

Later on, when you need to call this `Paginator`’s instance, just pass this name instead of `PID`:

```
GenServer.call(Paginator, {:blah, 42})
```